# Volumes mounting as folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am using `ecs-cli compose up` to run test-run a task in AWS-ECS

As far as I can tell, AWS-ECS supports `docker-compose` v2 syntax

On my local machine I have the following working tree:

```
~/Workspace/trafpro/docker-compose.yml
~/Workspace/trafpro/database/wordpress.sql
```

The contents of my `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *EDITED*
    volumes:
      - ~/Workspace/trafpro/database/wordpress.sql:/scripts/wordpress.sql
```

I then connect to the Docker container, and `docker attach` to the running mysql instance...to my dismay, `/scripts/wordpress.sql` is just an empty directory.

I know there is something wrong with my flow, do I need to upload the wordpress.sql into my `ECS` container?

Comment: How does `~/Workspace/trafpro/database/wordpress.sql` exist on the remote ECS host? The volume mount doesn't do any transferring of files if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mapping just the directory:

```
 - ~/Workspace/trafpro/database:/scripts
```